# ASP.NET Can't get the Complete View using ID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I'm creating a Adventure Cycle's project based on `MVC Music Store project`and I'm stacking into the `Address and Payment` for `User Shipping` including (First Name, Last Name, Address 1, Address 2...). When User fill in all the information, `Address and Payment` View will get the `SalesOrderID` and redirect to `Complete` View. But it didn't show the `Complete` when it done.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values)
{
    var order = new SalesOrderHeader();
    //var order1 = new SalesOrderDetail();
    TryUpdateModel(order);
    try
    {
        if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
        {
            return View(order);
        }
        else
        {
            order.AccountNumber = User.Identity.Name;
            order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
            order.Address = new Address();
            order.Address.AddressLine1 = values["AddressLine1"];
            //order.Address = new Address();
            order.Address.AddressLine2 = values["AddressLine2"];
            order.Address.City = values["City"];
            //Save Order
            BikeDBs.SalesOrderHeaders.Add(order);
            BikeDBs.SaveChanges();
            //Process Order
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
            cart.CreateOrder(order);
            //cart.CreateOrder(order1);
            return RedirectToAction("Complete", new { id = order.SalesOrderID });
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //Invalid - redisplay with errors
        return View(order);
    }
}
```

Here is `GET` action `Complete`:

```
public ActionResult Complete(int id)
{
    // Validate customer owns this order
    bool isValid = BikeDBs.SalesOrderHeaders.Any(o => o.SalesOrderID == id && o.AccountNumber == User.Identity.Name);
    if (isValid)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

Create Order:

```
//Create Order
public int CreateOrder(SalesOrderHeader order)
{
    decimal orderTotal = 0;
    var cartItems = GetCartItems();

    // Iterate over the items in the cart, 
    // adding the order details for each
    foreach (var item in cartItems)
    {
        var orderDetail = new SalesOrderHeader
        {
            SalesOrderID = order.SalesOrderID,
            Address = order.Address,
            Address1 = order.Address1,
            AccountNumber = order.AccountNumber,
            BillToAddressID = order.BillToAddressID,
            CustomerID = order.CustomerID
            //OrderQty = (short)item.Quantity,
            //UnitPrice = item.Product.ListPrice,
        };
        // Set the order total of the shopping cart
        orderTotal += (item.Quantity * item.Product.ListPrice);
        BikesDB.SalesOrderHeaders.Add(orderDetail);
    }
}
```

And here what happened when debugging in stack trace:

```
exception.StackTrace"at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()\r\n at AdventureCycle.Controllers.CheckoutController.AddressAndPayment(SalesOrderHeader order, FormCollection values) 
in c:\\MVC4_Apps\\Store Project(new)\\Store Project\\AdventureCycle\\Controllers\\CheckoutController.cs:line 63" string
```

That's what happens in Exception:

```
EntityValidationErrors = Count = 2 --> [0] = {System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult} 
                                    -->ErrorMessage = "The PostalCode field is required."
                                   [1] = {System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult} 
                                   -->ErrorMessage = "The PersonType field is required."
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't show the Complete when it done"? Do you  see the form again? Does it redirect to Complete action and show something else?

Comment: When `User` fill in the `Shipping Information` and click `Submit Order` button. It will redirect to `Complete` action. But in this case it is not redirect to `Complete` action, it returns to `Shipping Information`.

Comment: Then you get an exception in AddressAndPayment method. Debug your code and see what's wrong.

Comment: I could not see what's wrong in there when debugging. Could you tell me where I'm wrong ???

Comment: Change your catch block like this: `catch(Exception exception){return View(order);}` Now you can see the exception details while debugging.

Comment: It threw out an error `Validation failed for one or more entities.` @UfukHacıoğulları What does that mean?

Comment: Share the whole stack trace in the question.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I updated the whole stack already.

Comment: I still can't see it. Choose [Copy exception details to clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Didyouknowyoucancopytheexceptiondetailsw_F67C/image_2.png) in VS exception dialog and add it to your question.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I add it in my question.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Do you know what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Not yet. Is this the whole exception message? Any inner exceptions? Are you building on Debug mode?

Comment: `Inner Exceptions`: `Static Members --> Non-public members -->
_COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766
s_EDILock = {object}`. Yes, I am debugging on Debug mode.

Comment: Put that into question as well

Comment: I putted it into question. Do you have any clue?

Comment: I still have no idea. Are you trimming some parts of the exception messages? They don't look normal.

Comment: I updated an error above, I think it more clearly than the last one.

Comment: You need to fill PostalCode and PersonType properties according to that message.